# Connect an Existing QnA Knowledge base in Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

Sorry if this is a stupid question.  I just installed Bot Composer v2 and want to connect the bot to a QnAMaker knowledgebase.  This is what I have done:

1. Provision the necessary resources on Azure.
2. In the QnAMaker website, ([www.qnamaker.ai](http://www.qnamaker.ai)), create a knowledge base
3. Upload a File and have it populates the QnA pairs.  Save and publish (not sure if publish is necessary).
4. Create a new bot with the "Core bot with QnA" template.
5. Configure the bot to use the existing resource.

However, after doing the five steps, it doesn't give me the option to connect to an existing knowledgebase.  The only option I have is to create a new knowledge base, and the only option I have to populate the QnA pair is via a public URL - which is not a preferable option.

Since it doesn't work, I was trying to work the other direction by

1. Create a new bot with the "Core bot with QnA" template.
2. Configure the bot to use the existing resource.
3. Create a new Knowledge base with nothing in it.
4. Test the bot.
5. I checked QnAMaker website and realized the new empty knowledge base has been added.  I try to upload files to it - but it won't let me (Oops something went wrong)

The use case I am trying to do is to manage my knowledge (add new files etc) through the QnAMaker website, so content owner can manage their own content.  As a developer I will simply connect to the knowledge base.  However it seems that I can only manage the knowledgebase directly in the Bot Composer with reduced functionality (e.g. no direct import of a file).

Answer (score 1):

Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-qna-to-bot?tabs=v2x
to Add Existing QnA Maker KB to Bot Composer

[image]

Comment: Thank you but after read this article I was confused. It seems that this method is useful if I am building the not from stretch. However I am trying to use the qna template, which connects to a "default" knowledge base. I am just trying to change the connection so instead of the default knowledge base, I can use wherever kB I want. I tried updating their knowledge base I'd in the application JSON file but the bot still look at the default knowledge base.